# Do a redirection on div onclick event in a repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hy,

I facing a little problem to do something who seems easy...

In an ASP.NET page I have a repeater who present result from a research.
Until now an aspButton to do the job of redirection.
But I would like this redirection append when the user clic anywhere in my result line to replace my button.

I tried something in JavaScript and jquery but I can't get this to work...

Here is the code of my repeter :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProfil" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptProfil_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divLine" class="divProfil <%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "lineLignt" : "lineDark" %>">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnPerson" runat="server"/>
            <table class="table100">
                <tr>
                    <td class="rptLeft">
                        <div id="divName" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label ID="profilName" runat="server" Text='No data' CssClass="lbProfilNom" />
                            <asp:Label ID="profilFname" runat="server" Text='No data' CssClass="lbProfilNom" />
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                    <td class="rptCenter">
                        <asp:Label ID="store" runat="server" Text='No data' CssClass="lbSecondary" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="rptRight textCenter">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnShowDetails" runat="server" OnClick="BtnShowDetailsClick" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In the code behind section, nothing particular :

```
protected void rptProfil_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Person = (SearchItem)e.Item.DataItem;

    var id = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnPerson"); 
    var name = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("profilName");
    var fname = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("profilFname");
    var line = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("line");
    var city = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("city");
    var zip = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("zip");
    var store = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("store");

    id.Value = Person.PersonId.ToString();
    name.Text = Person.LastName;
    fname.Text = Person.FirstName;
    line.Text = Person.AddressLigne;
    city.Text = Person.City;
    zip.Text = Person.ZipCode;
    store.Text = Person.Level3Name;
}

protected void BtnShowDetailsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btnShowDetails = (Button)sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem)btnShowDetails.NamingContainer;
    var hdnPerson = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("hdnPerson");
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("ProfilDetails.aspx?id={0}", hdnPerson.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the following code

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowDetails" runat="server" OnClick="BtnShowDetailsClick" />
```

Try doing

```
<input type="button" onclick="redirect($(hdnPerson))">
```

and under script

```
<script>
var redirect=function(obj){
  window.location="ProfilDetails.aspx?id="+$(obj).val();
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I finally manage to do it thanks to you. I just put the onclick function on my div by the code behind to have the id in parameters.